# rails_admin can't modify nested model's fields with associated_model_config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, rails-admin

I'm trying to configure the nested model's fields in `:has_many` association, but nothing's happening. I'm on `Rails 4.2.3`, `mongoid 4.0.2`, `rails_admin 0.6.8`.

`Property` has many `Characteristic`s, `Product` has and belongs to many `Characteristic`s:

**/app/models/property.rb**

```
class Property
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :handle
  field :title, localize: true

  has_many :characteristics, inverse_of: :property
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :characteristics, allow_destroy: true

  validates :handle, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true
end
```

**/app/models/characteristic.rb**

```
class Characteristic
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :handle
  field :title, localize: true

  belongs_to :property, inverse_of: :characteristics

  has_and_belongs_to_many :products

  validates :property, presence: true
  validates :handle, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true
end
```

**/app/models/product.rb**

```
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :handle
  field :title, localize: true
  field :page_title, localize: true
  field :description, localize: true
  field :short_description, localize: true
  field :meta_description, localize: true
  field :meta_keywords, localize: true

  has_and_belongs_to_many :characteristics

  validates :handle, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true
end
```

**/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb**

```
require 'i18n'

I18n.available_locales = [:ru, :en]
I18n.default_locale = :ru

RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.main_app_name = Proc.new { |controller| [ "Babylon", "BackOffice - #{controller.params[:action].try(:titleize)}" ] }

  config.actions do
    dashboard
    index
    nestable
    new
    export
    bulk_delete
    # show
    edit
    delete
    show_in_app

    ## With an audit adapter, you can add:
    # history_index
    # history_show
  end

  config.model Characteristic do
    visible false
    label I18n.t(:characteristic).capitalize
    label_plural I18n.t(:characteristics).capitalize

    object_label_method do
      :i18n_characteristic
    end

    create do
      field :title do
        label I18n.t(:title)
      end
    end

    update do
      field :title do
        label I18n.t(:title)
      end
    end
  end

  config.model Property do
    visible true
    label I18n.t(:property).capitalize
    label_plural I18n.t(:properties).capitalize

    object_label_method do
      :i18n_property
    end

    list do
      field :title do
        label I18n.t(:title).capitalize

        formatted_value do
          bindings[:view].link_to value[I18n.locale], bindings[:view].rails_admin.edit_path(model_name: 'property', id: bindings[:object]._id.to_s)
        end 
      end
      field :handle do
        label I18n.t(:handle).capitalize
      end
    end

    create do
      field :title do
        label I18n.t(:title)
      end

      group I18n.t(:seo).upcase! do
        field :handle do
          label I18n.t(:handle)
        end
      end

      group I18n.t(:characteristics).capitalize do
        field :characteristics do
          label I18n.t(:characteristics)

          associated_model_config do
            field :title do
              label  I18n.t(:title).capitalize
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end

    update do
      field :title do
        label I18n.t(:title)
      end

      group I18n.t(:seo).upcase! do
        field :handle do
          label I18n.t(:handle)
        end
      end

      group I18n.t(:characteristics).capitalize do
        field :characteristics do
          label I18n.t(:characteristics)

          associated_model_config do

            field :title do
              label  I18n.t(:title).capitalize
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  ...
end

def i18n_property
  title_translations[I18n.locale]
end
def i18n_characteristic
  title_translations[I18n.locale]
end
```

So as you see, I tried to configure fields of `Characteristic` model in 2 places to show only `:title` field, but it still shows automatically all it can grab from the model, and doesn't even translate:

[image]

Please help find a solution to display nested fields right! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it's all because of the wrong order. To make all work properly, the order should be `Property` first, and only then `Characteristic`. I wish it was mentioned in official readme.